# Div height different between chrome/edge and firefo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a simple website with a navbar at the top, and an image that extends exactly from the bottom of the navbar to the bottom of the window (at the window's maximized size), such that the image fills up the rest of the screen, without a scrollbar. I'm putting the image in a wrapper div and I'll cut off any overflow, so it's the div sizing I'm worried about. My issue is that the sizing appears correct in Chrome and Edge, but in Firefox, the div does not extend to the bottom of the page. Here are the images for the three browsers... I removed the image, and gave the wrapper div a brown background so you can see it easily.

[image: Appearance on Chrome]
Appearance on Chrome

[image: Appearance on Edge]
Appearance on Edge

[image: Appearance on Firefox]
Appearance on Firefox

Here's my JS that sets the div height:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var homepageTopImageWrapper = document.getElementById("homePageTopImageWrapper");
    var browserBarsHeight = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
    var height = window.screen.availHeight - browserBarsHeight - 58;
    height += "px";
    homePageTopImageWrapper.style.height = height;
    console.log(window.screen.availHeight);
  }, 100);
}, false);
```

I added an event listener using JS to wait for all the DOM content to load, and then I calculated the correct height for my div by taking the availHeight and subtracting off 58px (the height of the navbar) and then subtracting the height of the toolbar at the top of the browser. The setInterval is so that the wrapper will resize right away if the user presses Ctrl+Shift+B.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<!--__________________________NAVIGATION BAR__________________________-->
    <div id = "navbarWrapper">

      <!--________Navigation Buttons________-->
      <div id = "leftNavbarButtonWrapper">
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./ourMission_desktop.html'">Our Mission</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./team_desktop.html'">Team</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./services_desktop.html'">Services</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./contactUs_desktop.html'">Contact Us</div>
      </div>

      <!--________Social Media Buttons________-->
      <div id="navbarSocialMediaImageWrapper">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/facebook_logo_white.png" alt="Facebook logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/twitter_logo_white.png" alt="Twitter logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/instagram_logo_white.png" alt="Instagram logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
      </div>

      <!--________Donate Button________-->
      <button id = "donateButton" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">Donate Now</button>
    </div>


    <!--__________________________HOMEPAGE CONTENT__________________________-->

    <!--________Top Homepage Image________-->
    <div id = "homePageTopImageWrapper">
      <img src = "<img src>">
    </div>
```

Finally, here's the CSS:

```
/*--------------------------------GLOBAL CONDITIONS--------------------------------*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@500;700&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------NAVIGATION BAR--------------------------------*/
#navbarWrapper {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#leftNavbarButtonWrapper {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  border-spacing: 1cm 0;
}

.leftNavbarButtons {
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
  padding: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
}

.leftNavbarButtons:hover {
  color: #c2c2c2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#donateButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2mm;
  top: 2mm;
  height: 1.1cm;
  width: 5cm;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.5cm;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#donateButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbarSocialMediaImage {
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
  width: 0.6cm;
  height: 0.6cm;
  margin: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
}

#navbarSocialMediaImageWrapper {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  height: 58px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6cm;
  top: 0mm;
}

.navbarSocialMediaImage:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*--------------------------------HOMEPAGE--------------------------------*/
#homePageTopImageWrapper {
  /*border: 3px solid green;*/
  background: brown;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: calc(100% - 1.5cm);*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any ideas on why this is working in Chrome/Edge but not in Firefox?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I find with CSS differences between firefox and chrome/edgechrome - it's usually firefox that behaves according to the CSS spec more often than chrome/edgechrome - so, when dealing with CSS, I make it look correct in Firefox first, then it usually works in other browsers - as pointed out in the answer, it's likely to do with box-sizing property and firefox is behaving correctly, and chrome is doing something incorrectly - in 16 years of making web sites, I've found this to be the simplest way to make sites that behave identically on all browsers

Comment: Try this: Set `body { margin: 0; }` In your CSS. It probably fixes issue for chorom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made the problem **so** complicated! You can reach your goal with only CSS styles and without the need to **JavaScript** codes. Here is the html and css that makes that:

```css
/*--------------------------------GLOBAL CONDITIONS--------------------------------*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@500;700&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

/* ------------------------------ */
/* I changed this part of code */
/* ------------------------------ */
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Poppins;
}

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------NAVIGATION BAR--------------------------------*/
#navbarWrapper {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#leftNavbarButtonWrapper {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    border-spacing: 1cm 0;
}

.leftNavbarButtons {
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    display: inline-flex;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
    padding: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
}

.leftNavbarButtons:hover {
    color: #c2c2c2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#donateButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2mm;
    top: 2mm;
    height: 1.1cm;
    width: 5cm;
    background: red;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.5cm;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#donateButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbarSocialMediaImage {
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    width: 0.6cm;
    height: 0.6cm;
    margin: 0 0.25cm 0 0.25cm;
}

#navbarSocialMediaImageWrapper {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    height: 58px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6cm;
    top: 0mm;
}

.navbarSocialMediaImage:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*--------------------------------HOMEPAGE--------------------------------*/

/* ------------------------------ */
/* I changed this part of code */
/* ------------------------------ */
#homePageTopImageWrapper {
    border: 3px solid green;
    background: brown;
    height: calc(100vh - 58px);
    /*position: absolute;*/
    display: flex;
    /*top: 58px;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*height: calc(100% - 1.5cm);*/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#homePageTopImageWrapper img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id = "navbarWrapper">

    <!--________Navigation Buttons________-->
    <div id = "leftNavbarButtonWrapper">
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./ourMission_desktop.html'">Our Mission</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./team_desktop.html'">Team</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./services_desktop.html'">Services</div>
        <div class="leftNavbarButtons" onclick="location.href='./contactUs_desktop.html'">Contact Us</div>
    </div>

    <!--________Social Media Buttons________-->
    <div id="navbarSocialMediaImageWrapper">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/facebook_logo_white.png" alt="Facebook logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/twitter_logo_white.png" alt="Twitter logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
        <img class = "navbarSocialMediaImage" src="../images/instagram_logo_white.png" alt="Instagram logo/link" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">
    </div>

    <!--________Donate Button________-->
    <button id = "donateButton" onclick="window.open('<link path>', '_blank')">Donate Now</button>
</div>


<!--__________________________HOMEPAGE CONTENT__________________________-->

<!--________Top Homepage Image________-->
<div id = "homePageTopImageWrapper">
    <img src = "img1.png"> <!-- your imag url -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I used `calc()` function of CSS and also used `vh` unit to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - unfortunately this isn't exactly what I'm trying to achieve, because the height of the wrapper resizes as you resize the window. I'm trying to get the wrapper height to stretch from the bottom of the navbar to the bottom of the screen while the window is maximized, and have it stay that height, even if I vertically shrink the window. This is why I used availHeight in JS.

Comment: @i'mlearningtocode I'm not sure what you mean, but as I know ```vh unit``` means **1% of the height of the viewport** and [is changing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vh)  when you change browser height instantly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a difference in the height or overall size of the navbar between any of the browsers. What I would do instead of letting Javascript do the work is use sizing with CSS and the `Height: exampleHeight;` and combine it with `box-sizing: border-box;` which will include the padding in the overall height of the navbar.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get what I want with just CSS - I want the height of the wrapper div to be the max possible height of the window (i.e. the height when maximized), minus the navbar and the browser's tabs/search bar. I can't access properties like window.screen.availHeight from CSS, right?

Comment: I get what you are going for with the same height of the navbar on all screens but It is a lot more mobile friendly when everything is responsive to the height and width of the screen. I personally use `vh` or `%` when sizing stuff.